# Google favicon crawler causing ActionView::MissingTemplate exception on Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, curl, favicon, google-crawlers

I got an `ActionView::MissingTemplate` exception every time **Google Favicon crawler** tries to get my *root url* accepting only the `image/*` format.

The crawler user agent is:

*Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:6.0) Gecko/20110814 Firefox/6.0 Google Favicon*

I can reproduce this exception with this command:

`curl -v -H "Accept: image/*" http://localhost:3000`

I'm using a custom layout, named omega (on `/layouts/omega` path), can this affect the framework like that?

Isn't this a misbehavior?

How can I solve this and serve the favicon?

The error log:

````html
ActionView::MissingTemplate at /
================================

> Missing template /layouts/omega/_index with {:locale=>[:"pt-br", :pt, :en], :formats=>["image/*"], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/samuel/www/myapp/app/views"
  * "/home/samuel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/kaminari-0.16.3/app/views"
  * "/home/samuel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/declarative_authorization-0.5.7/app/views"
  * "/home/samuel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"
  * "/home/samuel/www/myapp"
  * "/"


app/controllers/properties_controller.rb, line 280
--------------------------------------------------

``` ruby
  275             redirect_to root_path, status: :moved_permanently
  276           else
> 280             render '/layouts/omega/_index'
  282           end
  283         end
  284         return
  285       end
```

App backtrace
-------------

 - app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:280:in `show'

Full backtrace
--------------

 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:122:in `find'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:28:in `block in determine_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:143:in `with_fallbacks'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `with_fallbacks'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:28:in `determine_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
 - /home/samuel/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/benchmark.rb:303:in `realtime'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 - activerecord (3.2.22) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
 - app/controllers/properties_controller.rb:280:in `show'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:492:in `block in _run__3499709650331313942__process_action__3074038669074245940__callbacks'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:215:in `block in _conditional_callback_around_548'
 - marginalia (1.3.0) lib/marginalia.rb:77:in `record_query_comment'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:214:in `_conditional_callback_around_548'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:447:in `_run__3499709650331313942__process_action__3074038669074245940__callbacks'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
 - activerecord (3.2.22) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
 - rack-mini-profiler (0.9.7) lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:106:in `block in profile_method'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
 - journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
 - journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
 - mongoid (2.4.11) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `block in call'
 - mongoid (2.4.11) lib/mongoid.rb:133:in `unit_of_work'
 - mongoid (2.4.11) lib/rack/mongoid/middleware/identity_map.rb:33:in `call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
 - warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
 - activerecord (3.2.22) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
 - activerecord (3.2.22) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__4348557046124021977__call__3061323192353778014__callbacks'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:84:in `protected_app_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:79:in `better_errors_call'
 - better_errors (2.1.1) lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:57:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
 - quiet_assets (1.1.0) lib/quiet_assets.rb:27:in `call_with_quiet_assets'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 - activesupport (3.2.22) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
 - actionpack (3.2.22) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:83:in `call'
 - rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
 - rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
 - rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
 - rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
 - rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
 - honeybadger (2.0.6) lib/honeybadger/rack/error_notifier.rb:33:in `block in call'
 - honeybadger (2.0.6) lib/honeybadger/config.rb:189:in `with_request'
 - honeybadger (2.0.6) lib/honeybadger/rack/error_notifier.rb:30:in `call'
 - honeybadger (2.0.6) lib/honeybadger/rack/user_feedback.rb:29:in `call'
 - honeybadger (2.0.6) lib/honeybadger/rack/user_informer.rb:19:in `call'
 - rack-mini-profiler (0.9.7) lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:276:in `call'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
 - eventmachine (1.0.7) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
 - thin (1.6.3) lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
 - rack (1.4.7) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
 - railties (3.2.22) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
 - script/rails:6:in `<main>'
````